# How to prevent db from initialize when spring boot restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I started to learn spring boot and now currently working on a simple authentication project. But I have a problem. 
Database is always initialized.
I configure application properties like this.

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

I set initialization-model "never". But it does not work.
Db is consist of two tables: **users** and **roles**.
Of course **users** and **roles** has `ManyToMany` relation and has **user_role** table.

```
public class User {

//...

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id" , referencedColumnName = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

What could be a problem?

Comment: Can you share more details. Property you added is correct and should work. Is it causing you any failure or anything else?? If error is there you can use property -> spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

Comment: more details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using spring-data-jpa, you could set the following property:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`

The possible values are: create, create-drop, validate, and update.

On your case, it would be better set update.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want spring-boot to a reinitialize your db, then you should use the property `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false`

Comment: Thank for your answer. But it does not work for me. I configure `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false`. But data in db always be cleared when restart.